# Disable a javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to disable a javascript function depending on a choice of radio button.
If the radio button is set to 'Yes' then a function (in a field that auto populates a number of date fields) is disabled so the user is free to fill the field without auto populating other date fields.
Make sense?

Cheers

Aaron

Comment: Not really. Please add some code to help to explain yourself.

Comment: I have no code yet as I dont know if a function can be disabled. Its within MS Dynamics crm so you can enter each field and enable/disable any function but I need a way of doing that programmatically.

Comment: Give it a go, do some research and if you still have trouble, post your attempt and what the issue is

Comment: In javascript functions can be disabled/replaced. Usefull in e.g. unit testing. I think you want to choose to not execute the function instead of disabling the function, something a simple if statement should be able to do

Comment: There's no `function.disabled` property. There *are* many, many ways to stop code from running, but we can't see what the function *does*, what causes it to run when it *does* run, etc. -- so how can we help "disable" it? Show some HTML. Show the function, or at least *a* function. Show how that function is activated. My imaginary version of your code may not match up with the real thing.

Comment: Can't you just look at it another way and not disable the function, but simply check to see if the radio button is selected (or not) at the start of the function. IF it is selected, execute the code within the function, ELSE just end and don't do anything.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, i think i'll wrap code in the existing function to not fire if the radio button is set to yes. Apologies for the vague description, your replies did help me think it through. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use something like that:

```
$('#your_radio_button_group_id').change(function(){
   //use conditional if to check which radio has been checked
   if($('#r1').attr("checked"))
   {
      //disable/enable elements
   }
});
```

see the JSFiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/N9tBx/

Answer (score 0):

How are you?, maybe this code can help you(see the example https://jsfiddle.net/v1wm5k3j/):

Html:

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="op" value="1">YES
<br>
<input type="radio" name="op" value="0">NO
<br>
<button id="btn1" type="button">Click Me!</button>
</form>
```

Js:

```
function Example() {
    alert("Click Click click")
}

$('#btn1').click(function() {
    Example();    
});

$('input[name=op]').click(function() {
    check = $('input[name=op]:checked').val();
    if (check > 0) {
        $('#btn1').unbind("click");
    }else{
        $('#btn1').bind("click", Example);
    }
});
```